# Cloning the table rows in not working in js

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a table with checkbox. when i select the checkbox and click the copy button the selected row want to clone in to a new table with the selected rows. currently the selected rows in the table is not cloning. i want use JS no jquery. i added jsfiddle below.

```
function cloneTable() {
  var tabClone = document.getElementById('table');
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var row = tabClone.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if (chkbox.checked) {
        table.appendChild(clone);
    }
  }
  createTable();
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajaovi/4hcwp85n/5/)

Comment: i is not defined and also clone is not defined in your code

Comment: first of all check your code properly still you have undefined variables like row in var clone = row.cloneNode(true); is not defined. So test your code for undefined errors first.

Comment: What is `createTable()`?

Comment: Check the fiddle pls..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `function createTable` which leads to creating the table from a scratch. Only thing you need to do is append the table with a clone of the row and changing the checkbox to false for marking that the process has been done.

## EDIT

Here is the `function cloneTable` and above `cloneTable()` you add the creation of the "second table" for you:

```
var tableCopy = document.createElement('table');
tableCopy.id = "tableCopy";
tableContainer.appendChild(tableCopy);

function cloneTable() {
  var tabClone = document.getElementById('table');
  var rowCount = tabClone.rows.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var row = tabClone.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if (chkbox.checked) {
        chkbox.checked = false;
        var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
        if(tableCopy.rows.length == 0){
            var cloneHeader = tabClone.rows[0].cloneNode(true);
            tableCopy.appendChild(cloneHeader)
        }
        clone.cells[1].innerHTML = tableCopy.rows.length - 1;
        tableCopy.appendChild(clone);
        console.log(table)
                console.log(tableCopy)

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. but it appending next to the row in currnet table.. i want the selected row  in a new table..

Comment: Do you want to create a new table on every time you copy? Or copy rows from one table to second table?

Comment: copy rows from one table to second table

Comment: @Raja edited the answer now it copies it to a 2nd table :)

Comment: Thanks for the code Working Fine konkko.. It's Possible to display the table heading like in table one. Many Thanks :)

Comment: Edited the answer. Yeap you just check if there are any rows made in the tableCopy if not copy the first row of the original table. You're welcome :)